# generic methods: how to force using the most specialized method available

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overloading, generic-method

I defined a generic method `Use<T>` in an interface `IInterface`. I tried to make an implementation of that interface where the concrete implementation of the `Use<T>` method depends on the actual type `T`, and I want to always call the most specialized method. But it does not work:

```
    interface IInterface { void Use<T>(T other) where T : IInterface; }
    interface IChildInterface : IInterface { }
    class ImplementsIInterface : IInterface
    {
        public void Use<T>(T other) where T : IInterface
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ImplementsInterface.Use(IInterface)");
        }
    }
    class ImplementsChildInterface : IChildInterface
    {
        public void Use<T>(IChildInterface other) where T : IInterface
        { // idea: if other is IChildInterface, use this method
            Debug.WriteLine("ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IChildInterface)");
        }

        public void Use<T>(T other) where T : IInterface
        { // idea: if above method is not applicable, use this method
            Debug.WriteLine("ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IInterface)");
        }
    }
```

Here is my main method:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        IChildInterface childinterf = new ImplementsChildInterface();

        childinterf.Use(new ImplementsChildInterface()); // outputs "ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IInterface)"
                                                         // but should output "ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IChildInterface)"

        childinterf.Use(new ImplementsIInterface());     // outputs "ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IInterface)"
    }
```

The method that takes an `IChildInterface` argument is never called, although it should.

**Is there a way to make this work? Or is my approach fundamentally wrong?**

Note that it is a necessity that `IInterface` only has one method definition. I might enlarge the interface hierarchy at any time (and thus increase the number of implementations I could provide in an implementing class), but this should not lead to needing to add more method definitions in `IInterface`. Otherwise, the whole point of using interfaces (i.e. to be flexible) would be missed.

---

The answers I got so far all involve the need to cast. This is also something I don't want to do, since it makes the whole setup useless. Let me explain the broader picture of what I try to achieve:

Let's imagine we created some instance of an `IInterface` (like so: `IInterface foo = new ImplementsChildInterface();`). It will behave in a certain way, but it will always behave in the same way - no matter if we see it as an `IInterface`, an `IChildInterface` or an `ImplementsChildInterface`. Because, if we call some method on it, the compiler (or runtime? i don't know) will check what type it REALLY is and run the method defined in that type.

Now imagine we have two instances `i1` and `i2` of `IInterface`. They again are, under the hood, concrete implementations of `IInterface`, so they have a concrete behaviour, no matter through which glasses we seem them.

So when I run `i1.Use(i2)`, the compiler (or runtime?) should be able to find out what `i1` and `i2` REALLY are, and run the corresponding method. Like so:

1. Which type does `i1` have? `ImplementsChildInterface`, ok, then I'll look at the methods there.
2. Which type does `i2` have? `ImplementsIInterface`, ok, then let's see if there exists a method `Use(ImplementsIInterface ...)`. There is none, but maybe there is a fallback? `ImplementsIInterface` is a `IInterface`, so let's see if there exists a method `Use(IInterface ...)`. Yes, it exists, so let's call it!

Comment: You use the term "concrete implementation" and "specialized" as if C# generics were like C++ templates. They're very much not. I'm not saying this to be pedantic, but to point out that there's a fundamental difference in how these languages approach overload resolution, and if you work against the model you're going to have a bad time. If you want reliable invocation of the most concrete methods, think virtual methods, not generic methods.

Comment: @JeroenMostert By "think virtual methods, not generic methods" do you mean to leave interfaces out of it completely? Because I thought about changing `IChildInterface` like so: `interface IChildInterface : IInterface { override void Use<T>(T other) where T : IChildInterface; }`, but it seems this overriding is not possible. In classes it were possible, at least. I really appreciate your hint, because it makes clear that my approach is doomed. But I can't think of an alternative object model that works in C#.

Comment: "Which type does ... have?" If you want a run-time resolution of these questions, you need virtual methods or reflection (`is`, `as`). Generics will not help you as they look only at the compile-time type of the context they are used in. `ImplementsChildInterface.Use<T>(IChildInterface other)` can *never* be called through `IChildInterface`, because `IChildInterface` doesn't *have* that method. You can name it whatever you like, but as the signature doesn't match, it can't serve as an implementation for the interface. Only `Use<T>(T other)` can.

Comment: Why do you even have *two* methods in your class? Why not use one single interface and only one method?

Comment: You can have `Use<T>(T other)` do runtime type inspection, or use double dispatch and give `T` a virtual method that you call (but this assumes you can get specific on what `T` is, your current problem statement is too abstract to suggest an appropriate solution). In some cases `dynamic` is appropriate, although that should obviously be used with care (but it's the only mechanism that will do C#-like overload resolution at runtime).

Comment: @HimBromBeere you mean like `public void Use(IInterface other) { if (other is IChildrenInterface) {...} else {...}}`? I think this might do what I want... Thanks for asking the right, most simple, question!

Answer (score 2):

Neither `IInterface` nor `IChildInterface` have a member `Use<T>(IChildInterface other)` defined, but only `Use<T>(T other)`.

Your class `ImplementsChildInterface` on the other side has a method `Use<T>(IChildInterface other)`. As you declaring `childInterf` as a reference of type `IChildInterface` you can´t access that member, but unly those defined in the interface. So you should cast to the actual class in order to access the method accepting an instance of `IChildInterface`. But even then the generic implementation is used. So you should also cast your parameter to `IchildInterface`:

```
ImplementsChildInterfacechildinterf = new ImplementsChildInterface();
childinterf.Use(((IChildInterface)new ImplementsChildInterface()); 
childinterf.Use(new ImplementsIInterface());
```

Furthermore as you don´t use the generic type-parameter within your more specialized method, you can also omit it:

```
class ImplementsChildInterface : IChildInterface
{
    public void Use(IChildInterface other)
    { // idea: if other is IChildInterface, use this method
        Debug.WriteLine("ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IChildInterface)");
    }

    public void Use<T>(T other) where T : IInterface
    { // idea: if above method is not applicable, use this method
        Debug.WriteLine("ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IInterface)");
    }
}
```

Alternativly you may also add a method into your `IChildInterface`:

```
void Use<T>(IChildInterface other) where T : IChildInterface;
```

Now you can use

```
IChildInterface childinterf = new ImplementsChildInterface();
childinterf.Use<IChildInterface>(new ImplementsChildInterface()); // outputs "ImplementsChildInterface.Use(IInterface)"
```

which will print the desired output.

Comment: `childinterf.Use(((IChildInterface)new ImplementsChildInterface());` Casting still doesn't work

Comment: Have you also casted `childInterface` to the actual class? You need both. Alternativly let it be of that type already from its declaration: `ImplementsChildInterfacechildinterf = new ImplementsChildInterface();`.